# Cannot create credit memo for orders placed by Guests (NON LOGGED IN customer group)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, extensions, creditmemo

I am using **Magento CE 1.7.0.2**. Now the problem I face is that, if I attempt to create a credit memo for an order which is placed by a guest (ie. **NON LOGGED IN** customer group), it shows an **error** as follows:

**"Customer email is required."**

Although I can create an Invoice without any issue. The **payment methods** are:

1. Check /Money Order
2. Express NAB Transact (Authorize and Capture mode)
3. Paypal Checkout

The **only extension I am using that affects the checkout procedure** is "**Customer Credit Extension" from Magestore**.

So is it because of that extension I am using or some other magento problem??

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: In order to check if the extension is the problem, just disable it, create an order, invoice it, and try to create a credit memo.

Comment: Yes that extension seems to be the culprit.... I was able to create the credit memo.... Thanks @Marius

Comment: @Marius It's simple, but why not post this as a solution, and then Helly can accept.

Comment: @benmarks. This is not actually a solution from my point of view. It didn't solve the issue. And this looks like an "off topic" question.

Comment: @Marius I understand your perspective. However, the OP did state *"is it because of that extension I am using or some other magento problem??"* and you showed him/her the solution for determining it. IMO a *separate* question would be, "Why doesn't the extension work?" :-)

Comment: @benmarks. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check if the extension is the problem, just disable it, create an order, invoice it, and try to create a credit memo.

<sub>Because @benmarks requested, I've written this as an answer.

He made me do it. I didn't want to. :)</sub>

Comment: Thats alright. Actully, I need not to panic that why the "Extension is not working". As it is a paid extension, I will surely ask for support they are liable to give the same. But  thanks for your opinion. It took me a step ahead and I atleast came to knw the reason of error.

Comment: <3 social problem solving